# Executing Haskell expressions in GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am trying out Haskell using *Learn You a Haskell* and the interactive online environment [Try Haskell](http://tryhaskell.org)

I noticed that the interpreter on the page gives me weird errors when I try to define something or when I use certain functions.

For instance:

```
λ let nouns = [" hobo "," frog "," pope "]
not an expression: `let nouns = [" hobo "," frog "," pope "]'
```

or I get a parse error for something as simple as:

```
λ :t "hello"
<hint>:1:1: parse error on input `:'
λ
```

The expressions are taken verbatim from the book.

Comment: TryHaskell can't allow all the features of GHCi for whatever reason, be it security or incompatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Haskell is not full GHCi, since it is a relatively small project and giving you full access can present security risks. If you want to try GHC online, check out http://www.fpcomplete.com.

Answer (score 0):

in your .hs file, calling :t will NOT read into the ghci as "has type" : will be read as cons. If you want to find out the type of "hello" simply type it into ghci as :t "Hello"